Select a registros de mi tabla(0) de un dataset
Estoy aprendiendo VB net (VS2019) con mysql (xampp). Estoy armando una vista de productos, cada producto pertenece a 1 grupo de productos, ej.dentro del grupo aguas , tengo distintas marcas de aguas, sandwiches igual .... uso un data adapter volcando los registros a un dataset (Datos), que vinculo a un dataviewgrid (dvg2). Al inicio cargo el datagridview sin problemas, en el load del form, donde también tengo un combobox donde cargo los grupos. Me gustaria que cada vez que cambio el grupo en el combo , el dataviewgrid se refresque y se cargue solo con los productos de ese grupo elegido.
Por lo que entendi .. el dataset, en este caso llamado Datos y que contiene 2 tablas, (0) productos, (1) Grupos , estaria accesible? Como puedo seleccionar los registros por el criterio grupo (ya obtengo el id) contra la tabla productos perteneciente al dataset y volcarla al datagridview ? Espero se entienda, copio el codigo de carga .


    Private Sub buscaProductos()

        cboGrupos.Refresh()
        dgv2.Rows.Clear()

        SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT " &
                                    "a.ID_PRODUCTO,a.ID_GRUPO,b.DESCRIPCION AS GRUPO,a.CODIGO,a.NOMBRE,a.DESCRIPCION," &
                                    "a.CON_STOCK,a.STOCK,a.PUNTO_PED,a.COSTO_UN,a.LISTA1,a.LISTA2 " &
                                    "FROM producto a, grupo b " &
                                    "WHERE a.ID_GRUPO = b.ID_GRUPO " &
                                    "AND a.BAJA=0;SELECT ID_GRUPO, DESCRIPCION FROM grupo WHERE BAJA=0 ORDER BY DESCRIPCION"

        SelectCommand.Connection = con1
        miAdpatador.SelectCommand = SelectCommand

        miAdpatador.Fill(Datos)
        Datos.Tables(0).TableName = "producto"
        Datos.Tables(1).TableName = "grupo"

        'Combobox
        cboGrupos.DataSource = Datos.Tables(1)
        cboGrupos.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPCION"
        cboGrupos.ValueMember = "ID_GRUPO"
        cboGrupos.Text = ""
        cboGrupos.SelectedText = "Selecciona una opción .."

        'Datagridview
        dgv2.DataSource = Datos.Tables(0)

        With dgv2
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "#"
            .Columns(0).Width = 60
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "id_grupo"
            .Columns(1).Visible = False
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Grupo"
            .Columns(2).Width = 120
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Código"
            .Columns(3).Width = 140
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Producto"
            .Columns(4).Width = 160
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Descripción"
            .Columns(5).Width = 220
            .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Con Stock?"
            .Columns(6).Width = 50
            .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Stock"
            .Columns(7).Width = 50
            .Columns(8).HeaderText = "Punto Ped."
            .Columns(8).Width = 50
            .Columns(9).HeaderText = "Costo"
            .Columns(9).Width = 90
            .Columns(10).HeaderText = "Lista 1"
            .Columns(10).Width = 90
            .Columns(11).HeaderText = "Lista 2"
            .Columns(11).Width = 90
        End With

    End Sub




Mi recomendacion, deja de aprender eso, y cambia ya lo que estas estudiando a algo muchisimo mas moderno. Un ORM como EF o Dapper te soluciona mil problemas que tenes aca, y te facilitan la vida.. si estas aprendiendo, es un buen momento de huir de esto que es MUY pero muy antiguo...
